# Seeing $1/x$ as a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to show that by defining 
$$\langle u, f\rangle=\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon}+\int_{\varepsilon}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx$$

with $f\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$, we have $u\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ and find $u'$.

The tip is to use the mean value theorem. I did the second part with $u'$ but my problem is to show that it is well defined.

So I got
$$\int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx=\int_{\varepsilon}^{\infty}\frac{f(-x)}{x}dx$$

so

$$\int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon}+\int_{\varepsilon}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx=\int_{\varepsilon}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{x}dx$$

It would be great if I got $\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{x}$ because then

$$\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{x}=2\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{x-(-x)}=2f'(y)$$

for some $y\in(-x,x)$. But now how can I apply the mean value theorem to show that it is well defined?

Comment: Sign error: $$\int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx= -\int_{\varepsilon}^{\infty} \frac{f(-x)}{x}dx$$ Just a remark: another way to approach this construction is to begin with the distribution $\log|x|$ and take its derivative.

Comment: @rom As the integral domain and sup $|f'|$ are bounded you are done.

Comment: @5PM with the change of variables $x=-y$ we have $dx=-dy$ so I think that I have the sign correctly. Initially I got the minus but then I couldn't find $u'$.

Comment: @Vobo I don't quite see it, how do I make $f'$ to appear.

Comment: @rom You also flipped the limits of integration; that changes the sign.

Comment: Oh! right! Then I got $u'$ wrongly.

Comment: @rom Your integrand is bounded independently of $\varepsilon>0$ as $f'$ is, so what is your problem?